# Does get parameter get importance over post parameter?

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, get

Out of curiosity, I am sending both get and post parameter with same name and different values.

**JSP :**

```
<form action="actionName?param1=value1" method="post">
<input type="text" value="value2" name="param1" id="param1">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Servlet :**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
   doPost(request, response);
}
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
   String strParam1 = request.getParameter("param1");
}
```

I'm always getting value of strParam1 as "value1".

So, does it mean get parameter get importance over post parameter or it depends?

Comment: Have you overridden the `doPost()` method in the servlet ?

Comment: yes.. will update my servlet code in a minute..

Comment: Check your browser console after the request is made to clear your question

Comment: In browser console if I enter "param1" I get "<input type="text" value="value2" name="param1" id="param1">"

Answer (score 0):

Get and post are apparently handled differently. Confusing as I see many examples treating post submissions in the same manner as get requests.

The following article examines it in depth.

http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/dbms/Data/Courses/DBIS/Software/servlets/servlet_tutorial.html#user-interaction

> The doPost method uses the getParameterNames and getParameterValues
>   methods to get the form data.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    // first, set the "content type" header of the response
    res.setContentType("text/html");

    //Get the response's PrintWriter to return text to the client.
        PrintWriter toClient = res.getWriter();

        try {
            //Open the file for writing the survey results.
            String surveyName = req.getParameterValues("survey")[0];
            FileWriter resultsFile = new FileWriter(resultsDir
            + System.getProperty("file.separator")
            + surveyName + ".txt", true);
            PrintWriter toFile = new PrintWriter(resultsFile);

        // Get client's form data & store it in the file
            toFile.println("<BEGIN>");
            Enumeration values = req.getParameterNames();
            while(values.hasMoreElements()) {
                String name = (String)values.nextElement();
        String value = req.getParameterValues(name)[0];
                if(name.compareTo("submit") != 0) {
                    toFile.println(name + ": " + value);
                }
            }
            toFile.println("<END>");

        //Close the file.
            resultsFile.close();

        // Respond to client with a thank you
        toClient.println("<html>");
        toClient.println("<title>Thank you!</title>");
            toClient.println("Thank you for participating");
        toClient.println("</html>");

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            toClient.println(
        "A problem occured while recording your answers.  "
        + "Please try again.");
        }

        // Close the writer; the response is done.
    toClient.close();
    }
```